# How to display separate individual box per character with spacing between two box using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create output like this using CSS having single input for each word

Also if I click on any specific box, it should have cursor there and allow to type.
Like if there are 5 box, and I want to enter 3rd letter only, it should allow.

[image]

I've tried that is showing only underline per character

```
<input type="text" name="word_1" class="word-guess" maxlength="5" style="width: calc(5 * (1ch + 5.2px))" />
<input type="text" name="word_2" class="word-guess" maxlength="6" style="width: calc(6 * (1ch + 5.2px))" />
...
```

CSS Used

```
.word-guess {
font-size: 24px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 10px 5px;
border: 0;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-family: monospace;
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    to right,
    black 0 1ch,
    transparent 1ch calc(1ch + 5.2px)
    )
    bottom/100% 2px content-box no-repeat;
}
```

It's generating output like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [done something similar](https://css-tip.com/number-inside-box/) that you can easily reuse for input elements

```css
.word-guess {
  --c: #000; /* control the color of border */
  --w: 1ch;   /* control the width for each letter */
  --g: 5px;   /* control the gap between letter */
  --b: 2px;   /* control the border */
  --n: 6;    /* control the number of letters*/

  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: var(--w);
  font-family: monospace;
  width: calc(var(--n)*(1ch + var(--w)));
  -webkit-mask: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,
        #000  0 calc(1ch + var(--w) - var(--g)), 
        #0000 0 calc(1ch + var(--w)))
    0/calc(100% - var(--w)/2) 100% no-repeat;
  padding-left: calc((var(--w) - var(--g))/2);
  margin-right: calc(var(--w)/-2);
  color: #000;
  --_g: var(--b), #0000 90deg,var(--c) 0;
  background:
    conic-gradient(from  90deg at var(--b) var(--_g)),
    conic-gradient(from -90deg at right calc(var(--b) + var(--g)) bottom var(--_g));
  background-size: calc(1ch + var(--w)) 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="word-guess" maxlength="6">
```